# Compiling C to WebAssembly float returns 0?

Tags: webassembly

I have made a simple benchmark program to test some performance between WebAssembly code and javascript. The problem is that when calling my exported function, I am getting a `0` value whereas if I were to compile the C program using `gcc`, I would get the appropriate output. For example, `4.843003`.

I am just starting out on WebAssembly programming, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. When I return a hardcoded number, it seems to work fine in my Chrome JS console.

Flags I am using to compile :

```
 emcc -Os main.c -o main.wasm -s WASM=1
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

int MAX_SIZE = 1000000;
int MAX_RUNS = 1000;

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
float benchmark() {
    int i, j;
    float seconds;
    clock_t t;
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];

    srand(time(0));

    t = clock();
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_RUNS; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < MAX_SIZE; j++) {
            arr[j] = rand();
        }
    }
    t = clock() - t;

    seconds = ((float)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    return seconds;
}
```

I guess I am not quite sure exactly within JS code, what `importObject` is for. I have just followed a few tutorials to get some sort of output and came up with this by looking at an `wasm2wat` output:

```
const importObject ={
    env: {
      STACKTOP: 0,
      STACK_MAX:65536,
      abortStackOverflow: function(val) { throw new Error("stackoverfow"); },
      memory: new WebAssembly.Memory( { initial: 256, maximum:256 } ),
      table: new WebAssembly.Table( { initial:14, maximum:14, element: "anyfunc" } ),
      __memory_base:0,
      __table_base:0,
      _clock: () => {},
      abort: () => {},
      ___syscall146: () => {},
      _emscripten_memcpy_big: () => {},
      ___syscall6: () => {},
      ___syscall54: () => {},
      _time: () => {},
      ___syscall140: () => {},
      _printf: () => {},
      _rand: () => {},
      _srand: () => {},
      abortOnCannotGrowMemory: () => {},
      nullFunc_ii: () => {},
      nullFunc_iiii: () => {},
      nullFunc_jiji: () => {},
      ___lock: () => {},
      ___setErrNo: () => {},
      ___unlock: () => {},
      _emscripten_get_heap_size: () => {},
      _emscripten_memcpy_big: () => {},
      _emscripten_resize_heap: () => {},
      setTempRet0: () => {},
      tempDoublePtr: 0,
      DYNAMICTOP_PTR: 0
    }
};

WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("main.wasm"), importObject).then((m) => {
    const { instance } = m;

    const n = instance.exports._benchmark();
    console.log(n);
});
```

So I am not sure if this is actually proper... Any ideas in how I should proceed?

Comment: Please post your emcc build command including build flags.

Comment: @BumsikKim edited! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zakki said, **you are not supposed to run `.wasm` file directly,** unless you know what it means.

WebAssembly is a really minimal VM that only is capable of running basic operations. It doesn't have *any* system libraries. It cannot know what `clock()` means, it does not have any filesystem, and it cannot run TCP/IP networking...it really can not do *any* system operations.

Instead, Wasm can import external code. In the browser context Wasm can import JS code to emulate system libraries. This is why Emscripten exists. Emscripten is not only a C/C++ -> Wasm compiler but it is a complete toolchain that includes necessary JS runtime to emulate C standard libraries (libc).

In your case, you can see how `time()` emulated in JS side form the [Emscripten source code](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/791f8cb3e9e0038b91dcd1f0f1e0397d2f94cd52/src/library.js#L2004):

```
clock: function() {
    if (_clock.start === undefined) _clock.start = Date.now();
    return ((Date.now() - _clock.start) * ({{{ cDefine('CLOCKS_PER_SEC') }}} / 1000))|0;
  }
```

So it basically borrows JS `Date.now()` function to emulate it. **Therefore you cannot run `.wasm` file directly, you should run it in the Emscripten JS runtime.**

```
emcc -Os main.c -o main.js -s WASM=1
```

or you can make it in HTML and run it.

```
emcc -Os main.c -o main.html -s WASM=1
```

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` always return `0`, because `_clock` is not implemented.

Use emscripten runtime.

```
emcc -Os main.c -o main.js -s WASM=1
```

Or define them by yourself, like this

```
      _clock: () => { return Date.now() * 1000; },
```